# How to Splice multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

There may be a simple way but troubled me.

I'm trying to `Splice` a 2-dimension array as below :

```
removeChild(test[1].splice(currShape, 1));
```

But won't Splice it, and get me following error :

```
Type Coercion failed: cannot convert []@29258d59 to flash.display.DisplayObject.
```

Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `splice()` actually is working.  Note that the [splice()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29) method returns an `Array` containing the elements that were removed from the original `Array`.

You then pass the `Array` that `splice()` returned as the argument to `removeChild()`. And it is the `removeChild()` method that is failing ... It expects the the argument to be a `DisplayObject` not an `Array`, and so it throws the exception.

You can probably change your code to do the following, written on two lines for clarity:

```
var removedItems:Array = test[1].splice(currShape, 1);
removeChild( removedItems[0] );
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `splice` returns an array, and `removeChild` needs a `displayObject`.

Does this work?

```
removeChild(test[1].splice(currShape, 1)[0]);
```

Comment: Darn you beat me to it by a minute (I guess I type too much!) Leaving my answer b/c I prefer to write/read code that is less cryptic ;)